# Minimal example for creating a warm StanfordNLP parser

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I want a warm (already loaded) parser to parse inputs instead of creating a new instance each time I want to parse an input.

I want a parser that functions similarly to http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/ . I installed `stanford-corenlp` from Maven. I executed the `StanfordCoreNlpDemo` class.

But I am stuck at how I can embed the parser into my own program. Please provide a minimal example of creating a parser programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But bear in mind that:

- Stanford Core NLP != Stanford Parser; the former includes the parser along with other NLP tools.
- Core NLP eats a great deal of your RAM!

I've been trying to achieve the same. This is what I've got so far for a webservice, you could do something similar with a singleton.

```
    public class NLPServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
            this.pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        text="blah, blah, blah.";

        // create an empty Annotation just with the given text
        Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

        // run all Annotators on this text
        pipeline.annotate(document);

    }
}
```

Comment: Note that as the documentation states, the parser is *not* thread safe.

Comment: Actually, the parser has been thread safe since version 2.0, released in Feb 2012 ... I guess you found some outdated documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.ArrayCoreMap;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

public class getentity{
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
     Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse,sentiment");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

        Annotation annotation= new Annotation("project is good but management is bad, work-culture is good");
        pipeline.annotate(annotation);
        List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
        if (sentences != null && sentences.size() > 0) {

            ArrayCoreMap sentence = (ArrayCoreMap) sentences.get(0);
            Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
            for (CoreMap token : sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) {
                ArrayCoreMap aToken = (ArrayCoreMap) token;
                }
             SemanticGraph graph = sentence.get(SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation.class);

            String k=graph.toString("plain");
            System.out.println(k);

  }
  }
}
```

This particular code you can get all the entities in the sentence